# Are bounded functions that are square integrable, integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Can we say that if the function is bounded, i.e., $|f(x)|<b$ for some finite $b>0$ and it is square integrable, i.e., $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)^2dx$ has a finite value, the value of $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ will be finite.

Also, can we claim anything about absolute integrability?

For absolute integrability, I have tried using Cauchy Schwarz, but since limits are from 0 to infinity, I couldn't think of an alternate way that would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$. We then have

$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)^2dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx=-\frac{1}{x+1}\Big|_0^\infty=1
$$

However,

$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x+1}dx=\ln\left(x+1\right)\Big|_0^\infty=\infty
$$

Thus, $f$ is square integrable and bounded, but it is not integrable.

We also can't deal with absolute integrability either. The function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is square integrable and bounded, but not absolutely integrable. Demonstrating this is a lot more difficult, however, since this has a discrepancy between Riemann and Lebesgue integration. In the Riemann integral, $g$ is in fact integrable, but not in the Lebesgue integral. In both cases, however, we have that $g$ is by no means absolutely integrable.

Answer (score 5):

No, a bounded square integrable function is not always integrable. Take $f(x) = 0$ if $x \leq 1,$ and $f(x) = 1$ on $[1, 2],$ $f(x) = 1/2$ on $[2, 3],$ etc. so that $f(x) = 1/n$ on $[n, n+1].$

Then the integral of $f$ is the divergent harmonic series, but the integral of $f^2$ is $\zeta(2),$ and $f$ is clearly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

It need not be the case. For example, let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } x \in \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]\\ -1 & \text{ if } x \in (\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is bounded but not integrable and $f^2$ is integrable.

Comment: Your $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable (but not Riemann-integrable).

Comment: @TonyK You are absolutely correct. Looking at OP's profile, I assumed that OP is referring to Riemann integrability. Perhaps OP can clarify.

Comment: I see nothing in the OP's profile to suggest anything one way or the other.

Comment: I just went by a guess based on the topics in which OP has asked questions and to me it seemed more likely that OP may have not seen Lebesgue integration yet. I could be mistaken for sure but let OP clarify that. If Lebesgue integral (or Henstock integral etc.) was the topic then I will be happy to delete my answer and if Riemann integration was sought then I'm sure there not much to worry about.

Comment: @AnuragA thanks! And you're right, I have no clue what Lebesgue integration is haha